# react native share image url

Tags: react-native, url, share

there are two part of codes, the first : a page with **list of touchable image**  and the second: with onPress the image open in new page in full size.
till now every thing is fin. but in new page when I want to **share image url**, it doesn't work!!!
here is some part of my code:

***part one:***

```
const Images = [
  { url: require("../Images/dress.jpg") },
  { url: require("../Images/111.jpg") },
  { url: require("../Images/222.jpg") },
... 
]

export class Dress extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
...
<View>
            {Images.map((image, index) => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                key={index}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("ShowImage", {url:image.url})}
              >
                <Image source={image.url}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ))}
          </View>...
```

***part two (above onPress direct to new page)***

```
export class ShowImage extends Component {
shareMessage = async  (PhotoLink) => {
    console.log('myUrl'+PhotoLink)
    const result = await Share.share({
      title: "title goes here",
      message: ("hi"+PhotoLink),
    });
render() {
    
    return (
...
<TouchableOpacity 
   onPress={()=>this.shareMessage(this.props.route.params.url)}
>
...
```

when I use **local image** the result is: "hi3" or "hi4" or ...
when I use **web image from internet** the result is: "hi[object Object]"

I don't know where is the problem!! plz help me :)

Comment: hi , for this result "hi[object Object]" , at first change to : ` message: ("hi"+  JSON.stringify(PhotoLink)), `  and see what's return

Comment: what is the image.url?? console.log this and show us.

Comment: @Mohamadamin sorry for delay! here is console.log:
myUrl/static/media/dress.f29a7937.jpg

Comment: Your problem is with web image from internet? yes?

Comment: @Mohamadamin actually I don't know!

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Part1 code like this:

```
const Images = [
  { url: "../Images/dress.jpg" },
  { url: "../Images/111.jpg" },
  { url: "../Images/222.jpg" }, 
]

export class Dress extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {Images.map((image, index) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={index}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("ShowImage", {url:image.url})}>
            <Image source={require(image.url)}/>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

and Part2 like this:

```
export class ShowImage extends Component {
shareMessage = async  (PhotoLink) => {
    console.log('myUrl'+PhotoLink)
    const result = await Share.share({
      title: "title goes here",
      message: ("hi"+PhotoLink),
    });
render() {
    
    return (
...
<TouchableOpacity 
   onPress={()=>this.shareMessage(this.props.route.params.url)}
>
...
```

and try again. when you require an image it is converted to an object.

and if you want to use web image url, you can simply edit Part1 like this:

```
const Images = [
  { url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" },
]

export class Dress extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {Images.map((image, index) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={index}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("ShowImage", {url:image.url})}>
            <Image source={{uri: image.url}}/>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```